# Setup Soapui test suite to run on a specified proxy server

Tags: soapui

I currently have a test suite which utilizes my default proxy address. I now have a service that will only execute successfully with a specified proxy address. What i would like to do is  to have a second test suite setup in a way that  it runs on the specified proxy without having to manually change the proxy within internet options.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a very good question and i have never had to figure this out, but your question made me thing and this is what i found.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI 
import com.eviware.soapui.settings.ProxySettings

SoapUI.settings.setString( ProxySettings.HOST, "127.0.0.1" )
SoapUI.settings.setString( ProxySettings.PORT, "8080" )
SoapUI.settings.setString( ProxySettings.USERNAME, "abhishekasthana" )
SoapUI.settings.setString( ProxySettings.PASSWORD, "password" )
SoapUI.settings.setString( ProxySettings.EXCLUDES, "abhishekasthana.com" ) 
log.info SoapUI.settings.getString( ProxySettings.ENABLE_PROXY, "No Value set" )
SoapUI.settings.setString( ProxySettings.ENABLE_PROXY, "true" )
log.info SoapUI.settings.getString( ProxySettings.ENABLE_PROXY, "No Value set" )
```

You should look at [com.eviware.soapui.settings](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/settings/package-summary.html) if you want to set any other preferences. Also check out [soapUI tutorial](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/tips-a-tricks.html#1-accessing-properties-settings-and-names) on doing the same. SoapUI people suggest an [alternate](http://www.soapui.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2690) method of doing this but i haven't tried this as yet.

This is what my proxy setting looks like when i ran the above code in soapUI OS's groovy step.

[image]

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks Abishek, I've tried the following, which works, but i'm not sure if the changes are being made only you the settings file or if it affects anything else:



System.properties.putAll( ["http.proxyHost":"197.85.200.92", "http.proxyPort":"8080"] )

Comment: not sure what you mean? are you asking me what your code will do or something else?

Comment: Apologies for the breakdown in my english. The code that I posted above successfully sets the proxy in order for the test suite to execute. What I would like to know is, by having a "System.properties.putAll" would any other proxy addresses be affected other than that for soapui? For example, the existing Selenium tests that are a part of Continuous Integration?

Comment: Groovy uses Java underneath and i think using the System.properties command will update java so anything that uses java to find the proxy will get impacted.

Comment: i've tried the method that you've provided above, but doesn't work. I have SoapUI 4.5.2

Comment: what error do you get? when you try my method. I have also tried this on soapUI 4.5.2

Comment: Works in SoapUI 5 as well.